# El Gamal with Elliptic Curve in Java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, elliptic-curve, elgamal

For academical purposes, I am looking for a possibility to implement ElGamal with Elliptic Curves (for encryption and decryption) in Java. I would like to know if this is possible by using only the Java standard library or is this only possible by using third party libraries?

For this problem, all I have found were threads that are at least 5 years old. My hope is that something has changed since then.

Comment: Check [`BouncyCastle`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) - point 5.4

Comment: Do you know if there is a good documentation of how to implement it? I can see here that the package contains an implementation but I can't find any way how to do this.

Comment: Do you want to create a new implementation yourself? Or use one already implemented? I mean - for academic (learning) purposes you can create yourself an implementation using standard Java tools, but your question doesn't contain any question. What do you have problem with exactly? (you can see the source codes of the BouncyCastle too)

Comment: My goal is to encrypt a message with AES and to encrypt the secret key with EC El Gamal. I have already initialized ECElGamalEncryptor and I encrypted an ECPoint successfully. It's just that I don't know how to encrypt the AES secret Key using ECElGamalEncryptor.

Comment: This question would probably better received if you focus on encrypting (or rather, encoding) the AES key and by showing your current effort performing ElGamal encryption.